# How to explain the verbal structure of "Il était trop chaud pour pouvoir être mangé"?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, infinitif, passif

I have seen this phrase in the fairy tale *Boucles d'or et les Trois Ours*:

> Il était trop chaud pour pouvoir être mangé

I do not know which grammatical structure does the phrase "pouvoir être mangé"  follow?

It is something like this:

> infinitif + infinitif + nous

and the meaning seems

> to be to be able to eat.

Can anyone unscramble the structure and its counterpart in English?

Comment: Could also be simplified as "Il était trop chaud pour être mangé". By adding "pouvoir" we introduce the possibility of the thing to be [eaten]. But this possibility is directly negated by the fact that "Il était trop chaud". This is more an emphasis on the fact that there was this underlying possibility. And therefore there is a choice (to eat) that could not be made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est **pour** suivi de l'**infinitif** de « pouvoir » lui même suivi de l'infinitif passif « être mangé ».

La préposition **pour** devant un infinitif indique le but. On pourrait aussi avoir dans cette phrase : **afin de** (d'être mangé), tournure  plus littéraire que **pour**.

**Pouvoir** indique une possibilité, ici quelque chose qui est faisable.
Si quelque chose « peut être mangé » ça veut dire qu'on peut le manger. La règle est que le verbe qui suit « pouvoir » doit être à l'infinitif. Donc « pourvoir être ». Et **pouvoir**  est suivi ici de l'infinitif passif : « être » suivi du participe passé.

On pourrait dire la même chose en supprimant le passif  :

> Il était trop chaud pour que quelqu'un puisse le manger.

Avec **pour que** et pas **pour** tout seul.

---

It's *pour* followed by *pouvoir* followed by the passive infinitive of *manger*. The verb following *pouvoir* must be in the infinitive. Therefore *être mangé*.

Preposition *pour* followed by the infinitive indicates an infinitive of purpose. The equivalent of the English "to" followed by the verb.

*Être mangé* is a passive infinitive: infinitive of *être* followed by the past participle of the verb *manger*.

"It was too hot to be eaten."

Answer (score -3):

Le plus simple est de dire : il est trop chaud à manger.
                             il est trop froid à boire.
                              c'est trop compliqué à comprendre.
                              c'est trop dur à faire